# Date format in saved and returned entity (Spring-Data)

Tags: spring-boot, orm, spring-data

When I save entity in my repository personRepository.save(person) this returned object has a date in the format like this: Wed Dec 21 13:38:00 CET 2016. How I can change it to format like: 2016-12-21 13:38:00.732? Where this conversion is done, how this can be changed?  In my database date saves in this format: 2016-12-21 13:38:00.732.

```
    @Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "update_date")
    private java.util.Date updateDate;

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>  {}
```

Comment: "my database date saves in this format: 2016-12-21 13:38:00.732". Incorrect. The tool you are using to view your database displays it in that format. A date is a date. Wed Dec 21 13:38:00 CET 2016 is the result of calling toString(). To display it in a given format use a formatter suitable for your purpose.

Comment: The tool is debuger in eclipse on field java.util.Date in entity. I have another dao class (criteria query), where I get this entity (the same entity ) and there is a format 2016-12-21 13:38:00.732

Comment: You can print a date in all kinds of different formats using various solutions depending on where you want to write it. In the standard Java API you can use an instance of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.htmlclass to print dates in a specific format.

Comment: Strange is that calling toString in the same entity, for the same type of field shows the date in different formats depending on the used repository

Answer (score -1):

You should use "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime". First of all, you change your person entity

```
@Entity
public class Person {    

    @Column(name = "update_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;

}
```

Then, update datetime in somewhere like PersonalImpl

```
     import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

     Class PersonalImpl {

        void updatePerson(...){
            Person person = new Person();
            //do update person data
            person.setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        }

    }
```

PostgreSQL 9.5 show db
2014-09-10 07:59:14.822

Comment: Why? Why exactly should he use that?

Comment: Hi Alan Hay, I just recommend him use this for further format datetime. then If we load person information (e.g for API).

Comment: Then, We will override JsonDeserializer or JsonSerializer org.joda.time.DateTime with any format